# Find Subgraphs inside a Connected Component from a NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, connected-components, network-analysis

I have built a NetworkX Graph containing 50000 Nodes and about 100 Million edges. I have a list of all connected components of this group using nx.connected_components(G) method. This method results in me having clusters of nodes such that each node has a path to reach every other node in that cluster. Now what I want is, in each of these connected components, I want to find subgraphs/sub-clusters such that each of these subgraphs are connected to each other by exactly one edge. Is there a method in NetworkX that I can use directly or any other way in which I can get this done? Sorry I am very new to graph theory so need a little direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then for each subgraph, you want to find all [graph cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) of size 1, i.e. you want to find all edges, that if taken away partition the graph into two subgraphs. These edges are called [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) and there are efficient algorithms to find them. The implementation in networkx is accessible via `networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called [minimum spanning three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). Using `networkx` you can do it like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6)])
nx.draw(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

However, I'm a little bit in doubt if `networkx` is able to perform on so many edges according [to this benchmark](https://www.timlrx.com/2019/05/05/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages/). I have tested `connected components` algorithm on `igraph`, it worked for me as well (and, of course, much faster), so you might also like to look for `igraph` based solutions.

#### Result

[image]